# wordpress the_title will split

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

hello I am creating my own theme on wordpress and i want to split the `the_title()` function into array all i want is the last item on array will be on `<span>` and the other one is on `<h1>`.
i tried this

```
$str = the_title();
$val = explode(" ", $str); // also tried implode
echo "<pre>";
print_r($val);
echo "</pre>";
```

but it only return array with no items
hope someone will help me.
this wat i really want to be the output 
   `<h1> This is a <span>Title</spam></h1>`
thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request for a third party software, here namely Wordpress. For these please first use the vendors resources like the Wordpress Codex, Wordpress Support Forums or other support resources that are dedicated to that software in specific.

Comment: check this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `the_title()` as it automatically display the current title of the page.
Beside this Use `$post->post_title;`.

Lets suppose a sample sentence `This is a Title`

```
<?php
global $post;

$str = $post->post_title;
$exp = explode(" ",$str);

echo "<h1>".$exp[0].$exp[1].$exp[2];
echo "<span>".$exp[3]."</span></h1>";

?>
```

**Output will be:**

```
<h1>This is a<span>title</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following instead of `$str = the_title();`

```
$str = get_the_title();

-or-

$str = the_title('', '', false);
```

documentation : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: Explaining *why* and linking to relevant documentation makes the answer [more useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/185667).

Answer (score 0):

Please use get_the_title() instead of the_title().

Beside is the link for complete understanding :--
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title